# Convert Rails 2.0.2 action recored query to rails 4.1.5 Rails action recored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-2

I have Sql Query :

```
@orders = Order.find(
  :all,
  :include => [[:shipping_addresses => :state], :order_status, :order_financial_status],
  :order => 'orders.id DESC',
  :select => ['orders.id, orders.created_at, orders.est_shipping_date, orders.order_contents_count, orders.pdf_filename, order_status.name, order_financial_status.name, shipping_addresses.state_abbr']
)
```

This is Rails 2.0.2 SQL query this sql fetch all recored from database table "Order" and is using foreign key to fetch other   data like shipping address.

I am trying to convert this same query to rails 4.1.5 Action record query .

```
Order.order("orders.id DESC")
```

this is giving me the order list but I want to know who i can handle :include  and :select part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your code this way and it'll work in Rails < 4 as well:

```
orders = Order.
         includes(table_names).
         order(order_columns).
         select(select_columns).
         all
```

Also, FYI:

The `select` clause isn't working like you want it to. To clarify:

```
Order.includes(:order_status).select("orders.id")
```

won't apply any `joins`. However

```
Order.includes(:order_status).select("orders.id, order_statuses.id")
```

won't apply the `select` that you want.

For minimum change in existing code, you should simply remove your `select` clause because it probably isn't working anyhow.

Alternatively, if you're ok with the subsequent changes that are required, you could use something like the following:

```
orders = Order.
         joins(:order_status). # add more tables & columns like you want
         select("orders.id, order_statuses.name AS order_status_name")
```

Then you will get your specified columns only. However you'll have to access order_status_name like so:

```
orders.first.order_status_name # instead of orders.first.order_status.name
```

There you go.

Comment: Order.includes([[:shipping_addresses => :state], :order_status, :order_financial_status]).order("orders.id DESC").select(['orders.id, orders.created_at, orders.est_shipping_date, orders.order_contents_count, orders.pdf_filename, order_status.name, order_financial_status.name, shipping_addresses.state_abbr']).all

This query is generating this 
SELECT orders.id, orders.created_at, orders.est_shipping_date, orders.order_contents_count, orders.pdf_filename, order_status.name, order_financial_status.name, shipping_addresses.state_abbr FROM "orders"   ORDER BY orders.id DESC

Comment: but its not including joins table

Comment: Remove your select clause then.

Comment: Thank buts its not helping... I want same query as above... i am converting that query into version 4.1.5 . if i remove select clause the i will not be able to get required result set.. :(